# Flutter - Switching between two images using GestureDetector

Tags: flutter, dart

I found this code and modify it to switch between two pictures.
it seems to me that is ok but ..... iT doesn't work.
Can you help me to understand why?
Thanks.
See below the full code.

```
import 'dart:ui';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(new MaterialApp(
    home: new MyApp(),
  ));
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  Image img; // variable named image to be named with the path
  Image imgUp = Image.asset("assets/images/pressed.jpg"); //pressed button path
  Image imgDown = Image.asset("assets/images/pressed.jpg"); //unpressed button path
  @override
  void initState() {super.initState();
    img = imgUp; //inizialize the image as imgUp version
  }
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Tap The Image!"),
          centerTitle: true,
        ), //AppBar section ended
        body: Center(child: GestureDetector(
            child: img,
            onTapDown: (tap) {
              setState(() {
                img = imgDown;
              });
            },
            onTapUp: (tap) {
              setState(() {
                img = imgUp;
              });
            },
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It probably doesn't work because you are using the same image for up and down. Please see here

```
  Image imgUp = Image.asset("assets/images/pressed.jpg"); //pressed button path
  Image imgDown = Image.asset("assets/images/pressed.jpg"); //
```

It works if you change the images, please see code below : [Note that the image changes back to imgUp as soon as you release the tap down.]

```
import 'dart:ui';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(new MaterialApp(
    home: new MyApp(),
  ));
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  Image img; // variable named image to be named with the path
  Image imgUp = Image.network("https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/faticons/32/arrow-up-01-512.png"); //pressed button path
  Image imgDown = Image.network("https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/faticons/32/arrow-down-01-512.png"); //unpressed button path
  @override
  void initState() {super.initState();
    img = imgUp; //inizialize the image as imgUp version
  }
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Tap The Image!"),
          centerTitle: true,
        ), //AppBar section ended
        body: Center(child: GestureDetector(
            child: img,
            onTapDown: (tap) {
              setState(() {
                img = imgDown;
              });
            },
            onTapUp: (tap) {
              setState(() {
                img = imgUp;
              });
            },
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

Comment: Glad it worked. I request you to accept and like the answer please.

Comment: I'm new! How to " I request you to accept and like the answer"?

Comment: Please see this image - https://i.stack.imgur.com/uqJeW.png . There should be a similar check arrow below my answer. Please click on it to make it green just as in the image. And up-vote (also called like) on the up arrow to make the number go from 0 to 1. Thank you so much.